# Why planInputPartitions is called multiple times in a micro-batch?

Tags: apache-spark, datasource

I'm developing a new Spark connector using data source v2 API (spark 3.1.1).
I noticed that the `planInputPartitions` method (in `MicroBatchStream`) is called twice every micro-batch.

What the motivation/reason is?

Comment: I have also observed that planInputPartitions() is being called multiple times (4 times in my case). Are you able to figure out the reason/motivation for this?

Comment: Unfortunately not